# XElement DataContractSerializer adding xmlns=""

Tags: wcf, linq-to-xml, xelement

I'm creating a simple XElement and sending it over the wire to a WCF service.

```
<root>
   <settings />
</root>
```

However, when it reaches the service operation it looks like this:

```
<root xmlns="">
   <settings />
</root>
```

Is there any way to prevent this empty namespace from being added?

Comment: That's the same thing.

Comment: I would prefer that it not be changed at all. Especially if we have automated tests comparing inputs and outputs that are not exactly as expected.

Comment: It is _not_ changed at all. The two XML fragments mean exactly the same thing. If your tests find them to be different, then your tests are wrong.

Comment: Meaning the same thing is not the same as being the same thing.

Comment: @Henk I would prefer not to use string. Maybe I need to use a different serialized.

Comment: XElement is a Serializer, not a Serializee.